# Rails testing with fog/webmock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, cucumber, carrierwave, fog

I am using the fog gem to send carrierwave uploads to an AWS S3 bucket. That seems to be working fine, but when I try to run my cucumber tests I get:

```
You are using Excon 0.6.6. WebMock supports version >= 0.9.6
```

I have moved fog out of the test group in the gemfile (it's only in development and production). I've looked around for other people have thing problem, but I haven't been able to find anything.

My goal really would be to not use fog at all in the test suite, but just use the local file system.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that I was using an old version of fog. I had:

```
gem 'fog'
```

In my gemfile when I needed to have:

```
gem "fog", "~> 1.12.1"
```

That fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I was about to chime in and let you know as much. I think a `bundle update fog` would also do the trick (without needing to lock to anything in particular or change the gemfile). Glad you were able to get yourself back on track so easily though.